# How do I implement this specific choice user interface in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, user-interface

I am new to making apps using Android Studio and need some help with design.
I am currently making an application using Java on Android Studio. When creating a user account, I want the user to select their location but I'm having trouble finding a way to implement it according to my design. Here's images of how I want the UI to work:
[User clicks on the city option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJxjW.png)

Then the app should open up a page which has a list of states (which i think should be a fragment):
[User selects Selangor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYzAg.png)

Based on the users choice of state, it should open a new page with a list of cities in the chosen states:
[user selects Ampang](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pcy3s.png)

Once the user has selected the City, it should return back to the registration page, with the city value filled in: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HqTNV.png)

How do I properly implement this? I've avoided using the nested spinner as other parts of my app include the same page by page design, and don't want to avoid this.

I tried using a dependent nested spinner to choose the location, even though it works, it doesn't look the same as my design.